# What program would you use to do simple querying on tabular data?

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel

I often receive data in Excel files and want to some simple lookups the way I would with SQL. In Excel, doing something like `select b.field from a join b on a.a1 = b.a1 and a.a2 = b.a2;` is doable with a vlookup and concatenated fields, but only works if the match is unique. Matching on multiple rows becomes a problem.

I'm looking for suggestions on a lightweight app that will let me drop my Excel tables in and query against them.

I've considered installing something like a MySQL/Postrgres DB, but it seems like overkill for just creating temp tables and running quick queries against them.